# Gettings Diff between two dates.

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there any alternative way apart from DateDiff in SSRS report. I need to get the difference between two dates date1 and date2 in "days". i have a limitation of not using the in built function  "datediff"  in SSRS

Regards,
jaipal

Comment: Why can't you use datediff? There is a .net one in SSRS, and the SQL one. Are you confusing the 2?

Comment: What kind of datasource (SQL, Flatfile, etc) are you using? If SQL, which one - SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL...?

Comment: Mark,These are the custom reports to be developed for an online CRM solution and online crm dosnt support certain built in fucntions like "DateDiff".

Answer (score 0):

Simple `=date1-date2` should work if there are no time parts in your dates.